# oracle query to check multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have employee information in 3 different table.
table have below information

table emp1 :

```
empid dep salary
1     BI   100
```

table emp2 :

```
empid dep salary
1     PS   200
2     PS   null
```

table emp3 :

```
empid dep salary
1     Sales   300
2     Sales   400

select * from emp1 union
select * from emp2 union
select * from emp3
```

Output:

```
empid dep salary
1     BI   100
1     PS   200
1     Sales 300
2     PS    null
2     Sales 400
```

If employee belong to dep=BI then display BI salary
If employee belong to dep=Sales then check if that employee also belong to PS. If he belong to'PS', then check 'PS' salary is not null, if it is not null, then display PS salary for both PS and Sales dep row as like below.

```
empid dep salary
1     BI   100
1     PS   200
1    Sales 200
2    PS    null
2    Sales 400
```

Without joining emp2 and emp3 i need to achieve this logic

Answer (score 0):

We can try using conditional aggregation along with analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        MAX(CASE WHEN dep = 'PS' THEN salary END) OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS dep_salary
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT empid, dep,
       CASE WHEN dep = 'Sales' AND dep_salary IS NOT NULL
            THEN dep_salary ELSE salary END AS salary
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions inside a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT empid,
       dep,
       CASE
       WHEN dep = 'Sales'
       AND  COUNT(CASE WHEN dep = 'PS' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY empid) > 0
       THEN SUM(CASE WHEN dep = 'PS' THEN salary END) OVER (PARTITION BY empid)
       ELSE salary
       END as salary
FROM   (
  SELECT empid, dep, salary FROM emp1 UNION ALL
  SELECT empid, dep, salary FROM emp2 UNION ALL
  SELECT empid, dep, salary FROM emp3
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp1 (empid, dep, salary) AS
SELECT 1, 'BI', 100 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE emp2 (empid, dep, salary) AS
SELECT 1, 'PS', 200 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE emp3 (empid, dep, salary) AS
SELECT 1, 'Sales', 300 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EMPID | DEP | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BI | 100 |
| 1 | Sales | 200 |
| 1 | PS | 200 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XxnUwUQW)

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to union all the data (did it as CTE) and then use Case expression with EXISTS subquery to check the condition for DEP='Sales' :

```sql
WITH        --  S a m p l e   d a t a :
    emp1 AS 
        (   Select 1 "EMPID", 'BI' "DEP", 100 "SALARY" From Dual    ),
    emp2 AS
        (   Select 1 "EMPID", 'PS' "DEP", 200 "SALARY" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "EMPID", 'PS' "DEP", Null "SALARY" From Dual   ),
    emp3 AS
        (   Select 1 "EMPID", 'Sales' "DEP", 300 "SALARY" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "EMPID", 'Sales' "DEP", 400 "SALARY" From Dual ),
```

... union all ...

```sql
    all_tabs AS
        (   Select * From emp1 Union All
            Select * From emp2 Union All
            Select * From emp3   )
```

... and main SQL with the result:

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select      t.EMPID, t.DEP,
            Case  When t.DEP = 'Sales' And EXISTS (Select 1 From all_tabs Where EMPID = t.EMPID And DEP = 'PS' And SALARY Is Not Null)
                Then (Select SALARY From all_tabs Where EMPID = t.EMPID And DEP = 'PS')
            Else t.SALARY
            End "SALARY"
From        all_tabs t
Order By    EMPID, DEP
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--       EMPID DEP       SALARY
--  ---------- ----- ----------
--           1 BI           100
--           1 PS           200
--           1 Sales        200
--           2 PS              
--           2 Sales        400
```